# Cannot access wp-admin after migration to another place

Tags: wp-admin, publish

I've been working in my blog.
Yesterday I made all back-ups (files and DB), i´ve changed the wp-config.php with the new user, DB name and password and I publised everything at my actual URL.

http://agenciamoka.com

My test URL is http://mokaweb.com.br/Moka/

Well, everything was good until I decided to access wp-admin.

When I tryied to access wordpress panel, it changes to the old URL.

Getting direct to the point:
every link points to the old URL.

Anybody knows what I have to do?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you copied the database? If so, you need to go back and use a database migration plugin to update the many places WP refers to the URL.

Comment: @WebElaine Now, I cannot access any wp-admin. Each one is ponting to the other. I'm saying that my development URL is linked to my domain and this one is pointing to development URL. Crazy. Is there another option to change the DB without using the plugin?

Comment: Just swap your wp-config.php files. That is what tells WP which database to connect to.

Comment: @WebElaine thank you very much, I could fix it after you tell me about DB wp-options

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is okay after follow this step by step.

> If you are changing the URL of your website at the same time as moving servers, you might need to do some additional MySQL work. For example, if you're changing from domain-one.com to domain-two.com, you'll need to change the siteurl and home options in the wp_options table.

[Moving a wordpress site - how to do it](https://css-tricks.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/)